# Bootstrap Woocommerce checkout columns not aligned

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I've been trying to align my checkout columns side by side for hours and finally decided to swallow my pride and ask for help, I can imagine it's something pretty simple but I can not find it,

When I [visit here](https://snugkitty.com/checkout/), and add anything to cart to see the problem, the columns are not aligned side to side, just underneath each other.

Running with Bootstrap + WordPress + Woocommerce.

SCREENSHOT

https://ibb.co/bK382Z8

CODE:

```
<div class="">
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="row" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox-form"> 
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>
                <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', '99fy' ); ?></h3>
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

                <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
                </div>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</form>
```

Comment: I can see that the image column and the variation select column are side by side, can you upload a screenshot of what you're referring to?

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem. However, good Stack Overflow questions must stand the test of time, and thus must be self-contained. Since you intend to shortly fix the website you are pointing to, the question will no longer make sense at that point, and will need to be deleted. Thus, it will help if you can edit the question to show the problem _in the question itself_, using code and screenshots. Additional links to the site are OK as a supplemental.

Comment: Of course. Here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/bK382Z8

Comment: Its the checkout page not the product page also. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The second column that is going under is not in the row, you can see this in HTML. Add the second column inside the row and it should work.

[image]

It's roughly supposed to look like this:

```
<div class="row" id="customer_details">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="checkbox-form">...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
     <h3 id="order_review_heading">Your order</h3>
     <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi there. Tried that and doesn't seem to change? Edited code in first post maybe this will help you :)

Comment: @Elliot See my answer, I've added a snippet of how it should be.